# Dump MySQL view as a table with data

Tags: mysql, view, export

Say I have a view in my database, and I want to send a file to someone to create that view's output as a table in their database.

mysqldump of course only exports the 'create view...' statement (well, okay, it includes the create table, but no data).

What I have done is simply duplicate the view as a real table and dump that. But for a big table it's slow and wasteful:

```
create table tmptable select * from myview
```

Short of creating a script that mimics the behaviour of mysqldump and does this, is there a better way?

Comment: The view includes a spatial column, which I've had problems with in import using CSV files. :(

Comment: Kinda closing the loop on this, finally got round to tidying up and releasing the script I crated to solve this. https://github.com/barryhunter/fakedump - it does as suggeted, just running the a query like "select * from view" and actually writing it to a mysqldump like format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here my problem is that I want to export view definition (84 fields and millions of records) as a "create table" statement, because view can variate along time and I want an automatic process. So that's what I did:

1. Create table from view but with no records

`mysql -uxxxx -pxxxxxx my_db -e "create table if not exists my_view_def as select * from my_view limit 0;"`

2. Export new table definition. I'm adding a sed command to change table name my_view_def to match original view name ("my_view")

`mysqldump -uxxxx -pxxxxxx my_db my_view_def | sed s/my_view_def/my_view/g > /tmp/my_view.sql`

3. drop temporary table

`mysql -uxxxx -pxxxxxx my_db -e "drop table my_view_def;"`

4. Export data as a CSV file

`SELECT * from my_view  into outfile "/tmp/my_view.csv"  fields terminated BY ";"  ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Then you'll have two files, one with the definition and another with the data in CSV format.

Comment: Almost the same as the fakedump script I ended up creating. only difference really, used a real temporary table (still with LIMIT 0) - that way could create the temp table with the same name as the view! But otherwise works great

Comment: humm supernice upgrade! also removes the need of dropping created table as it's temporary. Will try

Comment: Not sure if will help in your case, will have to arrange for the 'create temporary table ... ' and 'show create table' and  the 'select ... into outfile... ' to happen in the same actual connection. But might work.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be to do a query into a CSV file and import that.  To select into a CSV file:

From http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/1475/save-mysql-query-results-into-a-text-or-csv-file/

```
SELECT order_id,product_name,qty
FROM orders
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: If you don't have access to the mysql server shell, this wouldn't work. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 3):

OK, so based on your CSV failure comment, start with Paul's answer. Make the following change to it:

```
 - FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 + FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\'
```

When you're done with that, on the import side you'll do a "load data infile" and use the same terminated / enclosed / escaped statements.

Comment: Just to point out that if you use \ you need to escape the escape character, like this `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '\\'`.