# While taking table backup using mysqldump command, can we skip particular column..?

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to know, is there any option to skip particular column and take remaining table backup using mysqldump command.

If yes please let me know.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018669/mysqldump-table-without-dumping-the-primary-key

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541322/dump-mysql-view-as-a-table-with-data

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to move a table from one host to another but only include some of the columns and replace others with dummy data (like password columns). So I made a shell script that makes it possible to run a SELECT query and get INSERT statements as result.

You find the script here: https://gist.github.com/1239299